# An invalid or illegal string was specified when implementing basic Sharethis code

Tags: javascript, html, sharethis

I'm trying to implement ShareThis buttons on a page, but cannot get the basic options to work in FF or Chrome, on win 7 or Vista.

Chrome has no plugins. Have disabled FF plugins.

Not sure if the problem is some dumb mistake I'm making, or if it is with ShareIt JS code.

Steps:
1. Signed up
2. Went to http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools
3. Completed the 3 steps (changes: Added Pinterest and removed ShareThis button
4. Created a html file and pasted the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
      <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons...; /script>
      <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: 'beea8274-700e-4d53-aeff-393478c86a40'}); </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
      <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
      <span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
      <span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
      <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

On Page load in Firefox I get SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.
Email button popup just says 'loading....', and 'Pick one or more destinations:' has no options.

Pulled much hair out over this.

Thanks

Comment: you are not closing your script tag and some error is here

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons...;" </script>

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alien, that was bad editing on my part. I've checked source and that script tag is properly closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you deployed your html file on a server before testing it on a browser. If you are testing the html file directly by placing on your Desktop or some other folder, then it will not work. You need to deploy the html file to a server eg: Tomcat or whichever you are comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks K.C.Ashish Kumar. I hadn't deployed to a server, so was running from Desktop. Will deploy to the server and try it again.